# Probability of Jon living on my floor or being my neighbor

Tags: probability

I am moving into an apartment building of 4 floors, with 10 apartments per floor. My apartment has 2 neighboring apartments. 
Jon lives in the same building (and does not live in the same apartment as me).

What is the probability that Jon lives on my floor?
What is the probability that Jon is my neighbor?

I discover 2 residents living on my floor who are not neighboring me and are not Jon. 
With this new information: 
What is the probability that Jon is my neighbor? 
What is the probability that Jon lives on my floor?

Answer (score 2):

It is implicitly implied that Jon is equally likely to be in any one of the 39 remaining apartments. For the first two questions, just take the number of apartments that satisfy your criterion and divide by 39.

For the last two questions, the approach is essentially the same, except now there are only 37 possibilities for Jon's apartment, 7 of which are on your floor.